# Pasting an image from clipboard to a website

Tags: ajax, image, clipboard

I need to come up with a solution for users to be able to paste an image on to a website, then upload that image on to the web server. I'm not sure what the right solution for this - I am pretty sure javascript is out of the question because I don't think it can handle binary clipboard data (or any clipboard data?)

So, I'm not sure which way to go with this. Is this something possible with a Java applet? Or maybe a Flash SWF? Any other alternatives?

Answer (score 4):

Or this [free one](http://lassebunk.dk/2009/08/04/clipboard-java-applet/) (via another StackOverflow question)

Answer (score 2):

You can use pure JavaScript for this, assuming either Chrome or Chrome Frame. Since most other plugins or applets require a specific install action you might as well require installing [Chrome Frame](http://code.google.com/chrome/chromeframe/) as that will fix quite a bit more than just pasting events.

[View a live demo of a jQuery plugin that cleanly wraps the HTML Clipboard API](http://strd6.com/2011/09/html5-javascript-pasting-image-data-in-chrome/). This demo requires the Chrome browser.

Comment: the live demo is outdated

Answer (score 1):

[Rad Upload](http://www.radinks.com/upload/applet.php) (java applet). It's not free, but it is relatively cheap.