# Paste an image into a web page

Tags: javascript, image, clipboard, paste

Is it in any way possible, using javascript (jquery), html (5) to **get** a pasted image.

e.a a user click the printscreen button, opens a web page, clicks CTRL+V and the image is uploaded to the server (without the need to save to a local pc)

is it achievable through flash, java, any other technology?

ty

Comment: Here is a similar question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/361324/pasting-an-image-from-clipboard-to-a-website

Comment: possible duplicate of [Pasting an image from clipboard to a website](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/361324/pasting-an-image-from-clipboard-to-a-website)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Yes, this is possible in pure JavaScript, assuming either Google Chrome or [Chrome Frame](http://code.google.com/chrome/chromeframe/).

[View a live demo of a jQuery plugin that cleanly wraps the HTML Clipboard API](http://strd6.com/2011/09/html5-javascript-pasting-image-data-in-chrome/). This works by getting binary image data from the `Ctrl+V` paste event into JavaScript.

Comment: what about Firefox or Safari?

Comment: Give it a shot and let me know. I think it's related to the file API: http://caniuse.com/#feat=fileapi

Answer (score 0):

Google Docs supports drag-n-drop in everything but MSIE, however it still does not support copy & paste of images:

https://drive.googleblog.com/2010/10/drag-and-drop-images-in-documents.html

Answer (score -1):

I don't think it's possible using plain html/javascript, but you can do it using a java applet. Ex: [Radinks upload control](http://www.radinks.com/upload/applet.php)

Comment: @DanielXMoore "it's now possible" and "it's not possible with chrome + chromeframe" is two completely different things altogether..

Comment: Why, Chromeframe works in IE, and Chrome is a pretty popular browser, and FF is getting there. So is it more accurate to say it works in 60% of browsers and increasing?