# Using Javascript, is it possible to upload images along with text pasted from other web pages/clipboard?

Tags: javascript

In the question [Paste an image into a web page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4459287/paste-an-image-into-a-web-page), I have found that the reference in the answer works only when you copy images.

Is it possible to upload images from a mixed content with text and image? The use case is, user could copy rich content from some web page and paste into my rich editor. And the images embedded in the content will be uploaded to my server.

I can now obtain image objects, it will contain a remote url, I need image content from user's browser/cache. Usually I can retrieve the image remotely by server-side scripts, but some website has this anti-leach technique that I can't bypass. The user could always download the picture and uploaded to the server manually, I just want to my my site more user friendly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To answer your question, yes, it is possible to upload images and text, you may just need to parse the images' urls etc.

As for your implied question, "can I get images and text pasted from the clipboard:" Only in IE. JS doesn't allow access to clipboard data for security reasons (except in IE). You can't get the data in an element.onpaste event either; according to MDN (https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/element.onpaste):

"There is currently no DOM-only way to obtain the text being pasted; you'll have to use an nsIClipboard to get that information."

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply. Could you be more specific about "parse the images' urls"? I will receive an error by loading the image from a remote url. A 'cross domain security exploit?' maybe, I don't have a exact phrase for that on hand right now.

Comment: http://joelb.me/blog/2011/code-snippet-accessing-clipboard-images-with-javascript/ Here's an example of parsing out the image. Sorry, I lied; it is possible to get the pasted image data, just only in chrome and through the ff hack described there. I'm not sure how you'll handle that cross-domain url thing though.

Comment: Also, in saying that it should be possible to upload images and text to your server, I assumed that if you had data in a form, that you could do with that data what you please. I don't understand how the browsers handle image data in forms, but if it's there, you can do stuff with it.