# Copy clipboard image into webpage using Jquery

Tags: php, javascript, jquery

I want to implement copy clipboard image into webpage.

Ex. User click the printscreen button, opens a web page, clicks CTRL+V and the image is upload to the web page. Can it possible using jquery/javascript or PHP.

Is it possible in firefox?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Pasting an image from clipboard to a website](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/361324/pasting-an-image-from-clipboard-to-a-website)

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8743559/copying-an-image-to-clipboard-using-javascript-jquery

Answer (score 0):

I'm afraid not, no. You'll have to have your users save the screenshot to disk and then either (a) select it from the disk using a `<input type="file" />` element or (b) implement the HTML5 [Drag n' Drop API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DragDrop/Drag_and_Drop), allowing the user to drag the file into the browser window.